# App-routing-module loads app with component declaration, but not with loadChildren declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a HomeComponent that is loaded after I login to my app.
But that HomeComponent has a child, RedeComponent that I want to load when I enter my app.

When I leave the path with the component declaration it works, but when I have loadChildren:homeModule I can't even access the localhost.

> app-routing-module.ts

```
const perfilModule = () => import('./components/perfil/perfil.module').then(x => x.PerfilModule);
const contaModule = () => import('./components/conta/conta.module').then(x => x.ContaModule);
const utilizadorRecemRegistadoModule = () => import('./components/utilizador-recem-registado/utilizador-recem-registado.module').then(x => x.UtilizadorRecemRegistadoModule);
const pedidosModule = () => import('./components/pedidos/pedidos.module').then(x => x.PedidosModule);
const homeModule = () => import('./components/home/home.module').then(x => x.HomeModule);
const postsModule = () => import('./components/feed/posts.module').then(x => x.PostsModule);


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  //{ path: '', loadChildren: homeModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'feed', loadChildren:postsModule, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'perfil', loadChildren:perfilModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'pedidos', loadChildren:pedidosModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'conta', loadChildren:contaModule},
  { path: 'start', loadChildren:utilizadorRecemRegistadoModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

> home.component.ts

```
@Component(
    {   selector: 'app-home',
        templateUrl: 'home.component.html'})
export class HomeComponent {
    utilizador: Utilizador;

    constructor(private accountService: ContaService, private route:Router) {
        this.utilizador = this.accountService.utilizadorValue;
    }

    mailUtilizador() {
        return this.utilizador.mail;
    }

    navegarParaConsultarRede(){
        console.log("aqui1");
        this.route.navigate(['/consultarRede']);
    }

}
```

> home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HomeRoutingModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        RedeComponent
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

> home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
       path: '/consultarRede', component: RedeComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent
    },
   
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

> home.component.html

```
<div class="p-4">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hi {{utilizador.mail}}!</h1>
        <p>You're logged in!</p>
        <!--p><a routerLink="/users">Manage Users</a></p-->
        
        <button routerLink="/consultarRede" (click)="navegarParaConsultarRede()">Consultar Rede</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> rede.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-consultar-rede',
    templateUrl: './consultarRede.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./consultarRede.component.css']
})
export class RedeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

    @ViewChild('consultarRede') consultarRede!: ElementRef;
    
    ...
```

> consultarRede.component.html

```
<canvas #consultarRede class="consultarRede"  (window:resize)="onResize($event)" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)">

    <div id='subwindows-panel'>
        <table class='subwindows'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Primeira-pessoa:</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='user-interface' (change)='controlChange($event)'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<canvas>

<div>
    <p id="pop" *ngIf="popName!=undefined" style="width: auto; height: 38%" class="bubble speech">
    
        <a id="pop1"><strong style="color: #87c277">Name:</strong>{{popName}}</a>
        <br>
        <b id="pop1"><strong style="color: #87c277">Tags:</strong></b>
        <br>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let pop of popTags">
            <a id="pop3">{{pop}}</a>
            <br>
        </ng-container>
    </p>
</div>
```

So summarizing, I want to login to my app, be directed to HomeComponent, and from there, click the consultarRede button, and go to my RedeComponent.
When I leave **path: '', component: HomeComponent** it works, but with **path:'', loadChildren:homeModule** I can't even access login page in localhost.

Also, it was working before, but my teammate pushed something, and suddenly stopped working, so I don't even know what am I doing wrong now.

Comment: Angular version from 9 loadChildren syntax changed. You can use loadChildren import syntax

Comment: @GaurangDhorda yes, my first issue with not loading the page in localhost I believe I fixed it by that syntax, but now my button in HomeComponent doesn't redirect to RedeComponent, so I'm trying to figure that out

Comment: Inside home component html add route-outlet too! Then you can see home module components

Comment: So I figured it out, it wasn't redirecting to the correct url, so it was just staying in the home, instead of going to home/consultarRede, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad! Do we connect by email ?